# Can we merge 2 SQL with same logic with just marginally difference?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 SQLs,

```
    SELECT  @AlreadyPerformedActionsPerDay = COUNT(*)
    FROM    UserRewardActions URA
            INNER JOIN UserRewardActionTypes URAT ON URAT.ID = URA.UserRewardActionTypeID
    WHERE   URA.UserID = @UserID
            AND (
                    @UserRewardActionTypeID = 1 -- Because the register action is not per-date-wise(only allows once in lifetime)
                    OR CreationDateInUtc BETWEEN CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)) -- Inside Current Date
                );

    SELECT  @AlreadyRedeemedTheCurrentAction = 1
    FROM    UserRewardActions URA
            INNER JOIN UserRewardActionTypes URAT ON URAT.ID = URA.UserRewardActionTypeID
    WHERE   URA.UserID = @UserID
            AND CreationDateInUtc BETWEEN CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)) -- Inside Current Date
            AND URL IS NOT NULL 
            AND URL = @Url;
```

The fist SQL is the grabbing total number of user actions today. Second, is checking whether the current url is already used by the same user. This is fine. But I am looking to merge this query for performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, after reformatting your queries as below. I can see that they have different criteria.

```
DECLARE @from DateTime;
DECLARE @to DateTime;

SET @from  = cast(getutcdate() as Date);
SET @to = dateadd(DAY, 1, @from));

SELECT
                @AlreadyPerformedActionsPerDay = COUNT(*)
    FROM
                UserRewardActions URA
        JOIN
                UserRewardActionTypes URAT
                    ON URAT.ID = URA.UserRewardActionTypeID
        WHERE
                URA.UserID = @UserID
            AND
                (
                    @UserRewardActionTypeID = 1
                 OR 
                    CreationDateInUtc BETWEEN @from AND @to
                );

SELECT
                @AlreadyRedeemedTheCurrentAction = 1
    FROM
                UserRewardActions URA
         JOIN
                UserRewardActionTypes URAT
                    ON URAT.ID = URA.UserRewardActionTypeID
    WHERE
                URA.UserID = @UserID
        AND
                CreationDateInUtc BETWEEN @from AND @to
        AND
                URL IS NOT NULL 
        AND
                URL = @Url;
```

Comment: OK Is Temporary Table make sense here?

Comment: @user960567, no, a covering index on `UserRewardActions` for columns `UserID` then `CreationDateInUtc` probably does. Especially if you include `UserRewardActionTypeID` and `URL` in the `WITH` clause, It rather depends on the distribution of your data.